# GoDaddy php.ini on shared cpanel hosting... where, what and how?

Tags: php, configuration, hosting, shared-hosting

I've been pulling my hair out over how to actually use custom `php.ini` settings outside of the limited options available directly through GoDaddy's cpanel shared hosting.

It seems they're [documentation](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use-8913) is wrong or out of date.  I've spent *hours* on the phone with them; they're clueless.

I have identical `ini` files named as `php.ini`, `php5.ini`, `php56.ini` and `.user.ini` in both `/home/[username]` and `/home/[username]/public_html`:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING
error_log = /home/[username]/php_error.log
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 64M
max_input_vars = 10000
```

I've killed PHP processes endless times.  Waited overnight.  Sacrificed a goat.

Output from `phpinfo()` makes it clear that these configurations are **not** taking effect, and PHP is just dumping error logs in the directories containing the PHP files where the errors occur.

**What is the actual correct location and filename to get PHP configurations working on GoDaddy shared Linux cpanel hosting?**

Comment: if you can do a phpinfo(), check these fields: 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path', 'Loaded Configuration File', 'Scan this dir for additional .ini files', 'Additional .ini files parsed'.

Comment: Ah-ha... I lists `/opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini`, which I seem to be able to write to and it appears to take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, for me, seems to be to edit the "additional system" ini file at `/opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini`

The one caveat is that it will be overwritten if you change PHP settings via cpanel.  I can live with that, since this actually works.